# What is the best way to treat an object like an iterable in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, iterable

What is the best way to treat a single object as iterable?

For example, in the following case...

```
public void fun(Object o) {
    fun(new TempList(o));
}

public void fun(Iterable<Object> os) {
    try {
    for(Object o : os)
        // Write to server
        System.out.println(o);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      // log e
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Rewording this part.

A function already exists that takes an iterable of things and processes them (`fun(Iterable<Object> os)`). I am adding an alias for this function that takes a single item instead (`fun(Object o)`). This function will be called a lot by different instances, so I want the most resource efficient way to call the Iterable function with a single item (whatever creates the least trash/gets cleaned up the fastest).

Or, exactly as the question title says, **What is the best way to pass an `Object` to a function that requires an `Iterable<Object>`?**

Comment: An array isn't an iterable, but you can use the enhanced-for statement on it as well.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Another way is to use [Collections.singleton(o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-), which produces a one-item Set, which is an Iterable.

Comment: "but the function uses resources that are short lived, but much more efficient to use one than many trash ones" - not clear, do you might to explain a bit further about the motivation ?

Comment: (I upvoted the 2 perfectly valid answers that were downvoted)

Comment: @HuguesMoreau:  They're incomplete at best.  Depending on what the OP is trying to do, it may be better to use a stream with `forEach`.  All we know is that they're trying over two different types of things, and while we can offer a mathematically correct solution, it'd be best for everyone to get a **good** answer instead.

Comment: Fair enough. I saw that pattern the other day and got mildly irritated: OP was downvoting valid answers that were misguided by poor question, and making no effort at clarifying. Not saying that's the case here, sorry if I judged too quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for weekend. I thought question title + example code was plenty clear enough. I've reworded it to emphasize that all I care about is converting a single object instance into an iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Collections.singleton(item)`

Comment: Depends on what the user is doing. It may be more advantageous for them to create a stream for their iteration purposes. While yes, that has the disadvantage of duplicating some effort to get the right type of stream, it eliminates confusion around whatever it is the OP is trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can have a look on [`Collections.singletonList(object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)).

Comment: Depends on what the user is doing.  It may be more advantageous for them to create a stream for their iteration purposes.  While yes, that has the disadvantage of duplicating some effort to get the right type of stream, it eliminates confusion around whatever it is the OP is trying to do here.